# Turtlebot with Beagleboard?

Tags: ros, roomba, turtlebot, beagleboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a novice to beagleboards [1,2], of recent I and my friends have been toying with the idea of replacing the notebook computer in a turtlebot like set up (or even a bare roomba 5XX) with a beagleboard chip. I look for advice from beagleboard/ARM enthusiasts - is this at all possible ?

[1] : http://beagleboard.org/

[2] : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47000/turtlebot-with-beagleboard-??/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-10-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-10-29**:
a similar work has been done using the pandaboard which is very similar to the beagleboard. Although its not implemented on an irobot base but would be easier using ROS.. you can check more here http://tirokartblog.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/pandabot-running-ros/

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-29**:
@ankitravankar Looks cool ! thank you !

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-11-07**:
I would also recommend not to use beagleboard with kinect ... data acquisition is slow and it crashes all the time.. Pandaboard which is beefier and more robust can handle kinect and point cloud nicely. Also it comes with inbuilt bluetooth and wireless so working from workstation pc is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once you have installed Ubuntu on the machine you can install ROS
following the standard installation procedures at
ros (.) org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu  though you will
have to do more from source only a fraction of the binary packages
currenly build on the armel architecture

Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alex Pattinson](https://answers.ros.org/users/11006/alex-pattinson/) with karma: 16 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0